# Ng-Click of ui-grid cellTemplate inside factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ui-grid

I'm developing a website for my company, and I'm struggling while trying to trigger a function on cell's value click.

I'm using ui-grid and ControllerAs.

The function creating the table is inside my controller 'statusController':

```
function generateStatusCountChart()
{
    var postData = {
        'id'        : vm.id,
        'region'    : vm.region,
        'pageSize'  : PAGE_SIZE,
        'pageNum'   : vm.pageNum
    };

    dashboardsService.getStatus(postData).then(function (results) {
        vm.charts.statusCountChart.loading     = true;
        vm.charts.statusCountChart.gridData    = statusViewGraph.statusCountChart(results);
        vm.charts.statusCountChart.loading     = false;
    }).catch(function () {
        vm.charts.statusCountChart.failure     = true;
    });
}
```

This is the function inside statusViewGraph service:

```
function statusCountChart(results) {

   some code......

    var chartConfig = gridData.generateGridOptions(data,gridData.getStatusCountFields());

    return chartConfig;
}
```

And this is 'getStatusCountFields' inside 'gridData' factory:

```
function getStatusCountFields() {
    var specificColumnDef = [
        {
            name: 'result',
            displayName: 'Results',
            cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-contents',
            cellToolTip: false,
            minWidth: 50,
            cellTemplate: '<div><a ng-click="grid.appScope.vm.FunctionInStatusController()">{{COL_FIELD}}</a></div>',
            aggregationType: function (items) {
                return 'Total Results: ' + $filter('number')(items.length);
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'count',
            displayName: 'Count',
            cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-contents',
            cellToolTip: true,
            minWidth: 350,
            cellTemplate: '<div style="overflow: auto">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>'
        },
    ];
    return specificColumnDef;
}
```

So basically, what I want to do, is to call a function which defined in 'statusController', and the trigger would be ng-click inside cellTemplate as seen above. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check the spelling and capitalization of the function name in the controller.